# How do I solve this error while training Resnet-50 using transfer learning?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, resnet, transfer-learning

I am using keras.**version** '2.3.1' to train Resnet-50 using transfer learning.

I am getting an error when running the following code:

```
history = model.fit_generator(generator=train_generator,
                              epochs= 3,
                              validation_data=validation_generator)
```

error that I get is:

```
Epoch 1/3
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-a42d5d67d1c7> in <module>
      1 history = model.fit_generator(generator=train_generator,
      2                               epochs= 3,
----> 3                               validation_data=validation_generator)
      4 
      5 

ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have shape (2,) but got array with shape (9,)
```

Anyone knows how could I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It is simply because mismatch in output shape of model and your training y(target file). provide the complete script e.g. model_summary and shapes of your training data(x, y)

Comment: What should I add to the code? could you please explain using code?

Comment: Yeah, add you code and also details about your dataset. That will be grateful.